# How to get the Status of a Windows Process (Running or Terminated) using C language?

Tags: c, windows, process, triggers, status

I want to know weather the Process on Windows task manager is Terminated?
(that means I want to make a function like database trigger)
at the moment that some particular Process is terminated I want to do some task.

I tired it since day before yesterday in so many ways. but I did't get correct fit.

Thank you in Advance.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Windows.h"

int main()
{
HANDLE jvminst = GetCurrentProcess();

printf("%d %d \n",jvminst,WaitForSingleObject(jvminst,0));

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted? Maybe it just needs a minor fix we can help with.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, don't add it to comments - this way new readers can see the information instantly, instead of having to sift through comments.

Comment: Waiting for the current process to exit is pointless.  You need to identify the particular process that you want to watch and open a handle to it.  What do you know about the target process?  The process ID or the name of the executable, perhaps?

Comment: @Jesse Thank you for mentioning the way

Comment: @HarryJohnston I know the Process name.
               I want to know that process is terminated

Comment: You'll want to use the Process Status API to enumerate the processes in the system and identify the particular one you want.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HarryJohnston I am going to make my own Installer. for that first I check whether the machine had jvm, if not I'm installing jvm by running jvm file using ShellExecute method. those things are finished now. so at the moment I want to know when the jvm installation process is finished or not. id it finished I can continue my Installer by copying relevant files to destination..

Comment: In that case, instead of `ShellExecute` you should use `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecuteEx`, either of which will return a process handle which you can wait on.

Comment: However, for security reasons, I'd recommend that you install a local copy of the JVM (from a technology POV this just involves unpacking the relevant files to a subfolder of your application directory; I'm not sure whether you need to do anything special regarding the licensing) and use that rather than installing the full JRE.  Otherwise, if the users don't realize what you've done, they won't know to keep the JRE up to date (or to disable the web browser plug-ins) and will be vulnerable to attack.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks you for your suggestion. I'll do it that way. and I'll try to do this using CreateProcess and ShellExecuteEx and let you know the result. I'm new to C. so I need to find out every funtions you mention here before use them. thank uou

Comment: I found the solution.. thanks a lot for helping me @HarryJohnston
I did it using ShellExecuteEx

Answer (score 1):

Get the `HANDLE` of the process and use [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx).

Comment: Thank you @icktoofay for your quick reply. I'll try it and let you know. I'm new to this even I dont know what is HANDLE.

Comment: @Aspen: `HANDLE` is a Windows type that can refer to many kinds of things, including processes. There's a few ways to get a process's `HANDLE`, including [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320.aspx) for existing processes and [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) when starting new processes.

Comment: I did above code using your tips.
but I want to use Process name and then get the status of that process

Comment: I found the solution.. thanks a lot for helping me  @icktoofay 
I did it using ShellExecuteEx and also use WaitForSignal